# How to test if a checkBox is checked in ionic 2

Tags: angular, checkbox, protractor, ionic2

I am testing an application based on `ionic 2` and `angular 2` using `protractor`. I would like to test if and when a `ion-checkbox` is checked. Assuming that there is only one checkBox in the Page, I have tried this:

```
var checkBox = element(by.css('ion-checkbox'));
expect(checkBox.isSelected()).toBe(true);
```

The above test does not work properly as the property `isSelected()` is always `false` even if the checkBox is checked. As far as I know there is no property `isChecked()`. How can I test it then?

Comment: can you share your html page?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, the way I did this was by using Javascript, you basically use `indexOf` to  check its existence, check out my code below and apply to your situation appropriately.

```
  $scope.checkItem = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    // Picked items contain an array you push items into when the checkbox is clicked
    var check = pickedItems.toString();
    var ind = check.indexOf(item);
    console.log(ind);
    if (ind === -1) {
      // not checked
      pickedItems.push(item);
      console.log('Picked Items: '+pickedItems);
    } else {
      // checked, so maybe remove from array?
    };
  };
```

Comment: I didn't see `$scope` in angular2

Comment: You don't need `$scope`, that was just how I defined `checkItem` as a function that could be accessed by the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the object on the view with the controller.

On your HTML component add:

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="yourControllerVariableName"></ion-checkbox>
```

And on your controller declare it as a variable with name *yourControllerVariableName* and try the following:

```
expect(yourControllerVariableName.checked).toBe(true);
```